# Is there way to transfer all zip files from s3 bucket aws to other computer?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have module where I need transfer all zip files from s3 bucket to my network computers by by just connecting each ip address \xx.xx.xx.xxx. right now **im using laravel.**

```
exec('aws s3 cp s3://compexp/"11-10-2019"/"01150exp.zip"');
```

I have bucket name: **compexp** inside of bucket, there are created folder name: example **11-10-2019** inside of of dated folder there are zip files for the reference see the imported image.

[zip files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWZlV.png)

currently this is my reference, but i can't see how can i transfer the files from my network computers.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass another server as the destination to copy the contents. You need to copy the files locally first and the transfer to another server. A good way to sync a directory from S3 bucket contents is to use the sync command as mentioned here

```
aws s3 sync yourLocalDir s3://mybucket
```

Once you have all the contents synced up in your current directory you can just copy them to a different computer using scp command as mentioned here

```
scp -r yourLocalDir anotherHost:/directory
```

-r option of scp is to make sure you copy all the subdirectories recursively

Comment: I have the path look this.  exec('aws s3 sync s3://compexp/"11-10-2019"/"01790exp.zip" "\\xx.xx.xx.xxx\c\kitpos\update"');

Comment: You can't pass another server to copy the contents directly. You first need to download and then transfer

Comment: is it possible to download the files to my project folder?

Answer (score 4):

You can use flag --recursive together with `--exclude "*" --include "*.zip"` to copy only *.zip in folder "11-10-2019".
Regarding the network computers, Do you mean your internal network computers?

Comment: In this case, you should download all zip files to your server which runs exec() command first. Then use command `scp` to copy these zip files to your network computers.
** make sure that the server can access your internal network.

Comment: yah like @Juned Ahsan says. but is it possible to download the zip files to my laravel project folder?

Comment: I think it's possible to do so. It depends on your server config but you can give it a try.

Comment: yah thanks it works in command line of aws. however in my laravel by using this command exec('aws s3 cp s3://compexp/11-10-2019/01790exp.zip C:\xampp\htdocs') the zip files not downloading.

Comment: I see that your problem already solved in the other question. ;)